# Throwing exceptions in PHP7 for validation?

Tags: php, validation, exception, php-7

I'm updating a framework I finished a while ago. I got some feedback from the community, and decided to build a little portable MVC framework to house my packages.

I'm currently working on the router, and it's working perfectly when I feed the framework the URL it's supposed to get. I used `throw new Exception("MyMessage")` to make validating the URLs more object oriented and a lot simpler.

However, this is the first time I've ever attempted this, and it seems that my catch block is not catching the errors.

Specifically, whenever there is an error thrown in the `try` block, I want it to trigger my some code in the `catch` block. 
Here is the full `try/catch` block...

```
try
      {
        if (isset($url[0]) && isset($url[1]) && isset($url[2]) && $url[0] . $url[1] . $url[2] != "")
        {
          //Figure out if we're handling a package, or working in the package manager.
          if ($url[0] != "ignition" && $url[0] != "")
          {
            if (!file_exists("../packages/" . $url[0]))
            {
              throw new Exception($manager_error = "Package \"" . $url[0] . "\" not found.");
            }
            else
            {
              $this->package = $url[0];
              $this->path = "../packages/$this->package/controllers/";
            }
            unset($url[0]);
          }
          elseif ($url[0] == "")
            throw new Exception("No package name provided.");
          //Check if controller exists.
          if ($url[1] != "")
          {
            //Check if controller file exists.
            if (file_exists($this->path . $url[1] . ".php"))
            {
              $this->controller = $url[1];
              require_once($this->path . "$this->controller.php");
              unset($url[1]);
              //Check that controller exists in file.
              if (class_exists($this->controller))
              {
                $this->controller = new $this->controller;
                //Check that method exists in controller.
                if ($url[2] != "")
                {
                  if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[2]))
                  {
                    $this->method = $url[2];
                    unset($url[2]);
                    if (!empty($url))
                      $this->params = array_values($url);
                  }
                  else
                    throw new Exception("Method \"" . $url[2] . "\" not found in controller \"" . get_class($this->controller) . "\".");
                }
                else
                  throw new Exception("No method name provided.");
              }
              else
                throw new Exception("Controller \"$this->controller\" not contained in it's file.");
            } else {
              throw new Exception("Controller file \"" . $url[1] . ".php\" not found.");
            }
          }
          else
            throw new Exception("No controller name provided.");
        }
        else
        {
          //Check if we have one or more arguments, but less than the three
          //we need for a complete route.
          if (!isset($url[0]))
            $url[0] = "";
          if (!isset($url[1]))
            $url[1] = "";
          if (!isset($url[2]))
            $url[2] = "";
          if ($url[0] . $url[1] . $url[2] != "") {
            if ($url[0] == "")
              throw new Exception("No package name provided.");
            elseif ($url[1] == "")
              throw new Exception("No controller name provided.");
            elseif ($url[2] = "")
              throw new Exception("No method name provided.");
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception $e)
      {
        unset($url);
        $this->manager_error = $e->getMessage();
        $this->package = "ignition";
        $this->controller = "ignition";
        $this->method = "notFound";
        $this->path = "../package_manager/controllers/";
        $this->params[] = $this->manager_error;
        require_once($this->path . "$this->controller.php");
        $this->controller = new $this->controller;
      }
```

I've tried making a very simple version where I just echoed out some text and put some wrong URLs in the address bar to try and get SOMETHING from the catch block, but I haven't been successful.

I also would like to mention that this is in the constructor function of a class, if that makes any kind of difference.

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I change this script to get the exceptions to catch?

Comment: Hard to answer this without seeing code where Exception is being thrown.

Comment: I can post the whole script if you want. Does it matter where it's thrown as long as a conditional throws the exception?

Comment: At least show us the full `try/catch` code (which is what you want our help with).

Comment: There's the full `try/catch` block.

Comment: Just to cover all the bases, is there a namespace involved here?

Comment: Check the error logs. Many PHP engine errors won't throw a normal exception/any exception.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not experienced enough to really understand namespaces, let alone implement them. What I can tell you is that this is all contained in the constructor function of a class.

Comment: That's all in `__construct`!?

Comment: You know, the now deleted answer, though not related to exceptions, is probably a good start! Check your error logs or turn on error reporting

Comment: Yep. It's the app class for the framework that handles all the routing. @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy, no it's fine to do that.

Comment: @Steve the development server this is running on has the php.ini configured to error report. I got 3 or 4 fatal errors in the process of writing this.

Comment: Are you still getting errors? What are they?

Comment: @Allenph We like error messages tho... Help us help you...

Comment: Nope. Not currently getting any errors...at least not related to this. When catch block doesn't run I don't get an instance of one of my controllers so `call_user_func_array` doesn't work. 

Doing my best to find the PHP error_log right now. Went through php.ini and didn't see where it is at. Looking.

Comment: Created a log file and restarted Apache. Tried to produce errors, but the only thing it's complaining about is the `call_user_func_array` which is only a problem because the catch block is not creating the instance of my error controller.

Comment: your elseif statement is missing brackets

Comment: @DanieleD, that should be fine as long as the code following the conditional is only one line long.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem with `Exception` within a namespace is that you're probably throwing an extended child. An example is

```
namespace test;

class Class {
    public function __construct(){
        try {
            throw new Exception('Msg');
        } catch(Exception $err) {
        }
    }
}
```

So in this example we're throwing and catching `\test\Exception`. The namespace changes what exception class we're throwing. Where this goes wrong is this

```
try {
    new \BadClass(); // throws BadException
} catch(Exception $err) {
}
```

This isn't going to throw `\test\Exception` but your type hint is expecting that. As such, this will produce a fatal error because `catch` isn't matching the correct class in the type hint. There's a simple way to get around that

```
catch(\Exception $err)
```

Now your `catch` can catch all exceptions because they all, by definition, extend the base class. The `\` tells PHP to use the root `Exception` class.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure I'm following. I haven't declared a namespace, and I'm not getting any fatal errors. Nothing it being logged in my log file, nor are any fatal errors when I try to load the page relating to anything but the lack of the catch script producing my controller object. 

I went ahead and pre-pending the slash to my catch block, there wasn't a change. Am I missing your meaning?

Comment: Tried adding the slash to all of my throw statements as well to no avail.